# Gcc hide visibility of symbols coming from included static library

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, visibility, linker-flags

I have:

1. a shared library, say *libShared.so*, which contains a class `Bar`, with a method `int Bar::do(int d) const`
2. a static library, say *libStatic.a*, which contains a class `Foo`, with a method `int Foo::act(int a) const`.

The code of `Bar` is something like this:

```
//Bar.h
class __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) Bar
{
  private: 
    __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) int privateMethod(int x) const;
  public:
    Bar() {}
    int do(int d) const;
}

//Bar.cpp
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Foo.h"

int Bar::do(int d) const {
   Foo foo;
   int result = foo.act(d) + this->privateMethod(d);
   return result;
}
```

*libShared.so* is compiled with flag *-fvisibility=hidden*.

The problem is the following: I execute Linux command *nm -g -D -C --defined-only libShared.so*, and it results that **class *Foo*, along with its method, is visible outside *libShared.so*, despite having told to the compiler to hide everything except what is marked as "public"** (infact, they are marked as "T" by *nm*).

How can I avoid this? I want *libShared.so* not to expose symbols coming from its dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to compile **libStatic.a** also with flag `-fvisibility=hidden`.

Comment: sorry, but doing so won't prevent _libShared.so_ to use _Foo_?

Comment: I answer myself. It works! I suppose this is because a static linkage doesn't support symbols hiding, so the _hidden_ flag will take effect only when the objects in static library are used inside a shared one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please modify your answer with the cimments insight about hiding symbols in static and dynamic libs. Had discovered it just now

Answer (score 3):

`-fvisibility=hidden` only affects the default visibility of symbols generated by the compiler, it does not modify the visibility of existing symbols such as those obtained from static libraries.

Fortunately the linker does have a flag to do exactly that:  Use `-Wl,--exclude-libs=ALL` to change the visibility of global symbols from static libraries to "hidden", thus preventing them from being exported by your shared library.