# Strip symbols from static library, or import only specific symbols during linking

Tags: macos, linker, visibility

The setup is the same as in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883024/equivalent-of-allow-multiple-definition-for-macos).

I thought a bit more about the problem, and it turns out, of all symbols exported from the libraries I'm using, I only need a few of them. In the specific example that was given, I just need the functions `g()` and `h()`. `f()` doesn't need to be exported at all.

So what I'm trying to do now is to hide all symbols in each static library, except for those I actually need (in the example: `g()` from liba.a and `h()` from libb.a). I found some solutions that I believe will work in Linux (such as [`-Wl,--exclude-libs=ALL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66467168/523079)), but as stated in the previous question, Linux is not the problem, macOS is, and the macOS linker doesn't recognize that flag.

Is there a (preferably cross-platform, CMake-supported) way to either specify an exhaustive list of symbols I'd like to import from a static library when linking, or a way to process the static library so as to hide symbols that are not needed?

Answer (score 1):

On macOS the linker flag is `-hidden-l` instead of `-l`. Alas, AFAIK, there is no equivalent to `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` for all libraries. You will have to use `-Wl-hidden-l` for each library.

For example:

`-Wl-hidden-lz`

instead of simply

`-lz`

for zlib.